# Conditional formatting in mobile Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a weekly time sheet (which I have modified) for independent contracting.

I have a cell (B5) formatted for DATE ("Week Starting") as a data reference for the cells A16:A22) I want to automatically fill when I enter a value in B5.

I know how to write a simple formula based on my reference cell but I don't want nonsense/default dates to populate A16:A22 when my reference cell contains no value.

My formula for cell A16 is =B5+0. My formula for A17 is =A16+1. I carry that second formula down through A18:A22.

Image 1 is what happens when I leave my reference cell (B5) blank: A16:A22 displays default dates from 12/30/1899 to 1/5/1900.
[reference cell B5 blank generates default dates in A16:A22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a84hc.png)

I don't mind the default dates, I just don't want to see anything in A16:A22 untill I enter a proper value in B5, like this:[Desired view when B5 contains no value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjc1A.png)

And, this is what I want to see when I enter a value in B5:[Desired view in A16:A22 with value in B5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM5lJ.png)

What formula or combination of formulas can I insert in A16:A22 to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(B5="",,B5)
IF(B$5="",,A16+1)
```

Comment: Thanks, idfurw! Where do I insert those formulas?

Comment: The first one in A16 and second one in A17 and then copy and apply up to A22